# Asynctask doInBackground Methode never execute

Tags: gridview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I'm developing APP that fetch movies data from TMDB.com
 into gridview. So the problem is that `doInBackground` method is not executing. It does not show any LOG message, I get no error just blank screen displayed
I've tried to set the adapter in `onPostExecute` method instead in `OnCreateView` but no thing changed.

**ASYNCTASK SUBCLASS**

```
 public class fetchmovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
 private final String LOG_TAG = fetchmovies.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (params.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String moviejasonSTR = null;
    String size = "w185";
    String poster_path = "poster_path";
    String api_key = "my api key";

    try {
        final String base_move_url = " http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
        final String SORT_BY_PARM = "sort_by";
        final String Api_KEY_PARM = "api_key";

        Uri bulitUri = Uri.parse(base_move_url).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(SORT_BY_PARM, params[0])
                .appendQueryParameter(Api_KEY_PARM, api_key).build();

        URL url = new URL(bulitUri.toString());
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }
        moviejasonSTR = buffer.toString();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "movie string: " + moviejasonSTR);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);


        return null;
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
        try {
            return getMoviesDatFromJason(moviejasonSTR);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return null;
}

private String[] getMoviesDatFromJason(String movieJasonStr) throws   JSONException {
    final String RESULT = "results";
    // final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
    //final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
    //final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
    final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
    // final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";

    JSONObject movieJason = new JSONObject(movieJasonStr);
    JSONArray MOVIEARAY = movieJason.getJSONArray(RESULT);
    String[] imagearry = new String[MOVIEARAY.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < MOVIEARAY.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject movie = MOVIEARAY.getJSONObject(i);
        String poster_path = movie.getString(POSTER_PATH);
        String poster_uril = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" +   poster_path;
        imagearry[i] = poster_uril;

    }


    return imagearry;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {


}
}
```

**BASE ADAPTER**

```
 public class mcustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private String[] posterURL;

        public mcustomAdapter(Context context, String[] posterUrl) {
            this.context = context;
            this.posterURL = posterUrl;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return posterURL.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return posterURL[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            imageView = null; // created as a global view
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            Picasso.with(context).load(posterURL[position]).into(imageView);


            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

**OnCreateView OnCreate OnStart**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list_itempostr);
    grideview = (GridView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.movie_grid_view);
    grideview.setAdapter(movieadapter);
    movieadapter = new mcustomAdapter(getActivity(), imagearry);
    movieadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    grideview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });


    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updatemovies();

}

public void updatemovies() {
    String sortby = "popularity.asc";
    fetch.execute(sortby);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //updatemovies();

}
```

**FragmentMain**

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
 >
    <GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/movie_grid_view"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**image view**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_itempostr"



    />
```

**mainfest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exampel.android.mdb" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TMDB api, this will make it easier to fetch data.

Add this to your `app/build.gradle`

```
compile group: 'info.movito', name: 'themoviedbapi', version: '1.1'
```

And then use AsyncTask like this:

```
class fetchMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                String sortBy = params[0];

                tmdbDiscover = new TmdbApi("YourApiKey").getDiscover();

                if (tmdbDiscover != null) {
                    resultsPage = tmdbDiscover.getDiscover(new Discover().sortBy(sortBy).page(1));

                    if(resultsPage != null) {
                        moviesList = resultsPage.getResults();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Error:", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(moviesList != null) {
                movieArrayList = populateMoviesList(moviesList);
                adapterMovies.setPosts(movieArrayList);
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose that you are making project 2 in Android Developer Nanodegree, so [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/109766100514206800627?cfem=1) is the corresponding community where you can find lots of different questions/answers about projects and common issues

Comment: im sorry for not posting the whole code i created fetch as  fetchmovies class object

Comment: yh and sorry again  yes  im making  final project "1" in Android Developer

Comment: thank you bro im using picasso to handle loading  movies posters in the base adapter but i really want to knowwhy  my do inBackground method doe not execute what do i need to to do to make it works

Comment: I'd suggest you to double check your AsyncTask and use log statements to detect when your code stops working (e.g. print logs in onCreate and in updateMovies).